# Problem with PNG watermarks (with alpha channel transparency)

Tags: magento-1.9

When I use watermarks with alpha transparency, final images always has watermarks without transparency as expected. Sometimes it's just white background, sometimes black background.

[image]

How to fix this?

Comment: Please post your answer directly as an answer of your original question and not directly in the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After spending some time to find a right solution, I only found plugin called [Perfect Watermarks](https://github.com/magento-hackathon/Perfect_Watermarks), which replace GD to ImageMagik. Unfortunately I can't use it, because my PHP is 7 and I can't install this lib. After some code inspecting I found problem in library

```
lib/Varien/Image/Adapter/Gd2.php
```

Function

```
public function watermark($watermarkImage, $positionX=0, $positionY=0, $watermarkImageOpacity=30, $repeat=false)
```

use function

```
imagecopymerge()
```

, which has a bug with alpha transparency (if you want to learn more, check this comment http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopymerge.php#92787). How I solve this.

First I copy

```
lib/Varien/Image/Adapter/Gd2.php
```

to

```
app/code/local/Varien/Image/Adapter/Gd2.php
```

and add function from link I posted before. This is the only possible solution, because you cannot override a lib via config.xml (if you know another way, please post comment).

```
protected function imagecopymerge_alpha($dst_im, $src_im, $dst_x, $dst_y, $src_x, $src_y, $src_w, $src_h, $pct){ 
        $cut = imagecreatetruecolor($src_w, $src_h); 
        imagecopy($cut, $dst_im, 0, 0, $dst_x, $dst_y, $src_w, $src_h); 
        imagecopy($cut, $src_im, 0, 0, $src_x, $src_y, $src_w, $src_h); 
        imagecopymerge($dst_im, $cut, $dst_x, $dst_y, 0, 0, $src_w, $src_h, $pct); 
    }
```

After that, change

```
imagecopymerge()
```

to

```
$this->imagecopymerge_alpha()
```

in function

```
public function watermark($watermarkImage, $positionX=0, $positionY=0, $watermarkImageOpacity=30, $repeat=false)
```

After that my final image looks correct

[image]